# How to make an enchantment with more than standard allowed max level?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've seen a lot of lets plays and vanilla servers where players used swords with, for example, `Sharpness X` (but max allowed level is V). Or, also, I saw modded severs where you can donate and buy `Nano Sabre` from Industrial Craft with `Sharpness XVII`. How can I get such enchantment with in game methods? Is there some mod to do that? I tried `Enchantmets Plus` and `More Enchantments` mods but there is no such ability. I want be able to combine two `Sharpness V` (or any other enchantment, not only sharpness) books in anvil and get `Sharpness VI` book instead of `Sharpness V` again.

Comment: You've probably meant "Nano Sabre" :-) "Sable" means "соболь".

Comment: @OrcJMR, yes, of course, sabre too =)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combine sharpness 10 book with a sword in a anvil](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/375996/combine-sharpness-10-book-with-a-sword-in-a-anvil)

Comment: Closing an older question as a duplicate of a newer question because the newer question's answers actually contain commands that let you use anvils to do this, and this question only has "this isn't possible" and "use a mod".

Answer (score 7):

You can use commands to create items with any enchantments:

```
/give @p iron_sword 1 0 {ench:[{id:16,lvl:10}]}
```

There is no other way in vanilla. Someone else might know a mod that does that, though.

Comment: Thanks, I thought about that, but I need something not such obviously cheaty and without using command blocks... Mod, I guess.

Comment: Ok, lets hope someone else answers what you need. Nevertheless, I'll leave my answer for reference, it might be useful for someone.

Comment: @DmytroTsiniavskyi It doesn't need to be "cheaty" -- you can go to your Anvil Of Supremeness (aka Pit o' Lava), toss in your pair of `Sharpness V` books, and then `/give` yourself a `Sharpness VI` book. I do this all the time for recipes and such that I feel should exist, but don't -- and the end result is no different than a mod.

Comment: how do i enchant MULTIPLE enchants more than lvl 5?

Answer (score 3):

The mod you are looking for is called  [SuperEnchants.](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/2335274-172-forge-superenchants/)

*SuperEnchants mod allows you to enchant tools that have high levels. Note that you will need 30 levels and a enchanting table with maxed out levels. The higher the level you use to enchant, the luckier you will get. Enchanting something next to lvl 10 will lead to NEAR impossible..*

Enchantments that their limits have been increased or changed:

```
Sharpness Levels up to 10 [X] 
Fire Aspect Levels up to 10 [X] 
Looting Levels up to 5 [V] 
Knockback Levels up to 5 [V] 

Efficiency Levels up to 10 [X] 
Unbreaking Levels up to 10 [X] 
Fortune Levels up to 5 [V] 

Protection Levels up to 10 [X] 
Projectile Protection Levels up to 10 [X] 
Blast Protection Levels up to 10 [X] 
Feather Falling Levels up to 10 [X] 
Thorns Levels up to 5 [V] 

Power Levels up to 10 [X] 
Punch Levels up to 5 [V]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a no cheating aspect, then the mod *Orespawn* adds many new dimensions with various boss battles and new ores that can get you the type of enchants you are talking about. For example, once you beat the King you get King armour. This gives you, among others, Protection 10. If you want to not only get these enchantments but also want to add a certain amount of adventure and challenge to getting this rather end-game items then I would defiantly recommend it. If you want to read more, you can find the [Orespawn website](http://www.orespawn.com) has tons of Information that you may find useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can install TMI (TooManyItems). You can enchant whatever you want like silk touch X in a sword. I've install it on my Minecraft 1.7.2 and you can get spawners that you couldn't get like random fireworks spawner and charged creeper, xp orb and saddled pig. You can experiment with potions, favorite items (enchanted or not), Enchanted books, set time to sunrise, noon, sunset, and midnight. You can set creative, survival, and adventure immediately, rain on-off and delete mode if you like to delete in one click.