# Using custom enchanted books in an anvil (Minecraft)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

I recently started building some things with command blocks for a Minecraft server a friend is hosting. Is it possible through commands or some other way to combine a tool with an enchanted book that is unobtainable without commands? Whenever I have tried, it just gives the tool the highest survival level.

eg: Diamond sword + Unbreaking 5 book -> Diamond sword with unbreaking 5

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combine sharpness 10 book with a sword in a anvil](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/375996/combine-sharpness-10-book-with-a-sword-in-a-anvil)

Answer (score 1):

Anvils cannot process the book because it is higher than the survival level, which the anvil is coded to use. The only way to do this would be the

```
give @s diamond_sword{Enchantments{id:unbreaking,lvl:5}}
```

command or `/enchant` command.

Comment: Fixed your command for you. Only one `\`` is needed to make code: `\`test\`` not three.

Comment: Oh, thanks for that.

Comment: That's what I figured. Is there a way to change the highest level an enchant will go via datapacks?

Comment: I wouldn't know about data packs, since I'm mostly a vanilla player. I assume there would be one out there, but again, I wouldn't know.